# Strongly regular directed graph and its complementary graph..

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading a paper (Art Duval) about generalizing the strongly regular idea to directed graphs.. anyway, the lemma is:

Also, to be clear, the parameters are: $n$ - number of vertices, $k$ - valency, $u$ - number of common neighbors between non-adjacent vertices, $l$ - number of common neighbors between adjacent vertices, $t$ - number of undirected edges.

"If $G$ is an $(n,k,u,l,t)$ graph with adjacency matrix $A$, then the complementary graph $G'$ is an $(n, k', u', l', t')$ graph with adjacency matrix $A' = J - I - A$, where

\begin{align}
k'&= (n-2k)+(k-1)\\
l'&= (n-2k)+(u-2)\\
t'&= (n-2k)+(t-1)\\
u'&= (n-2k)+l
\end{align}

The proof begins by saying $A'$, $u'$, $l'$ and $t'$ need to satisfy $A^2 = tI+lA+u(J-I-A)$.
It states to evaluate $A'^2 = (J-I-A)^2 = ..$ this is where I get lost
\begin{align}
(J-I-A)^2 &= (n-k-1)J - (J-I-A) - (kJ-A-A^2)\\
&= (n-2k-2)J + I + 2A + (lA + t + u(J-I-A))\\
&= (n-2k+t-1)I + (n-2k+u-2)(J-I-A) + (n-2k + l)A\\
&= t'I + l'A' + u'(J-I-A')
\end{align}
How does is transition from $A'^2 = (J-I-A)^2$ to the rest?